# ng-bootstrap, how do I add a class to ngb-tabset?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

It does NOT seem possible to add custom css classes to the `<ngb-tabset>` tag.

When using `<ngb-tabset>` it generates this html:

`<ul role="tablist" class="nav nav-tabs justify-content-start">`

I need to add classes to the `<ul>`. How do I do that?

I want my `<ul>`to look like this:

`<ul class="nav nav-tabs custom-tabs move-left">`

Comment: you need to use host in order to do so and that to only if the viewEncapusaltion of ngb-tabset is set to none . Check this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/host)